# What's the most efficient way to transfer data from one AWS RDS instance to another

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, data-transfer

I am working for a client who uses multiple RDS (MySQL) instances on AWS and wants me to consolidate data from there and other sources into a single instance and do reporting off that.

What would be the most efficient way to transfer selective data from other AWS RDS MySQL instances to mine?

I don't want to migrate the entire DB, rather just a few columns and rows based on which have relevant data and what was last created/updated.

One option would be to use a PHP script that'd read from one DB and insert it into another, but it'd be very inefficient. Unlike SQL Server or ORACLE, MySQL also does not have the ability to write queries across servers, else I'd have just used that in a stored procedure.

I'd appreciate any inputs regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your overall objective is reporting and analytics, the standard practice is to move your transactional data from RDS to Redshift which will become your data warehouse. This [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/fast-easy-free-sync-rds-to-redshift/) article by AWS provides an approach to do it.

For the consolidation operation, you can use [AWS Data Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) which will allow you to migrate data column wise with following options.

- Migrate existing data
- Migrate existing data & replicate ongoing changes
- Replicate data changes only

For more details read this [whitepaper](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Storage/An_Overview_of_AWS_Cloud_Data_Migration_Services.pdf).

Note: If you need to process the data while moving, use [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/).

Comment: Regarding your suggestion to move to RedShift, currently there is also some PHP code that I run to get data from external third party tools via their API, into our RDS. Would RedShift support this as well?

Comment: Is the data you get from these APIs for reporting purposes? If so you can move them to Redshift.

Comment: Yes, and they have relevant Ids in our CRM web app that uses another MySQL RDS, so I can join and query them. However, some of the APIs need data cleansing and other manipulation, which is taken care of by PHP at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the [RDS migration tool](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/introducing-the-amazon-rds-migration-tool/)?

Comment: I can see a Snapshot Migration Feature, will try to figure out RDS migration tool. Is it capable of selective querying and transfer?

Comment: I do not think so. But I think you can do it before or after the moving isn't it?